# Android, when to load user data and where to store it

Tags: android

I recently started working on Android apps, and im having a hard time deciding what approach i should use for this issue. For simplicity sake, lets assume we are making an app identical to Instagram. I have a back end server that has all the user data. The user logs in, and is on the main activity and now :

- Should i fetch all the user data, all his photos, all his info now (directly after he logs in), and store it in somewhere, so when he visits the profile activity all his info is already on the device, or should i download all his photos and info when he clicks on profile? If its the first option, where should i store his data(photos,ext) after i download it? SQLite ?

Obviously this questions extends to other stuff as well, like should i download all his messages when he logs in, or should i download all his messages when he clicks on the messaging activity. Thank you!

EDIT: I am also new to Stack Overflow, and have been getting some down votes, if you are planning to down vote, could you please comment your reason as well, so i can get better.

Comment: _This question extends to other stuffs as well ..._ This is very broad. It depends on the nature and amount of data you want to store. Generally for pictures, you should store them locally, except if the picture is inherently supposed to change often (like excerpts from news or something like that). This is both opinion-based and too broad to me, you have to break down your question into several cases, and investigate them individually. Good luck for your project though !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get going with this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad to answer properly. In my personal opinion this will depend completely on what you are trying to build. For example, ideally you would be combining local database and remote database for the best user experience. As we know, items locally are faster to load, therefore it will be a better user experience. However you can't store everything locally as you mentioned with messages. Instead in this use-case you would only save the last 10-20 messages. Sql-lite with Room as a wrapper is a great combination for a local database.

[Android Basics](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp)

[Room database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)